# Django - app's static files loading in a template, not in another

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a crazy issue about static files in an app (Django-Autocomplete_Light, DAL) I'm using to implement form autocomplete.. https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/907

I'm able to load a DAL form in my home-page, which is extending `base.html`. The same DAL form does not work in another template which is extending the same `base.html`. I mean, the DAL JS files are not loaded in the other template..

the string `{{ form.media }}` is in `base.html` after jquery import, as required by the [doc](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst#using-autocompletes-outside-the-admin) of DAL.

What might be the problem?

This is what is not loaded in the other template:

```
<link href="/static/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/static/autocomplete_light/select2.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/autocomplete_light/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/autocomplete_light/autocomplete.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/autocomplete_light/select2.js"></script>
```

**edit:**

this is my `base.html`

```
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load helper_tags %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>MySoundList | {% block title %}Home Page{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="MySoundList">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    {% block specific_css %}{% endblock %}


    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    {% get_available_languages as languages %}

    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="{% change_lang %}">

    {% for lang_code, lang_name in languages %}
        <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ lang_code }}" href="{% change_lang lang_code %}">
    {% endfor %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'custom.css' %}" />

</head>
<body>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <p class="browserupgrade">
        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser.
        Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.
    </p>
<![endif]-->

<div class="MainWrapper">
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
</div>

<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

{{ form.media }}

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

{% block specificjs %}{% endblock %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'custom.css' %}" />

<script src="{% static 'custom.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the page where the form is not working:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load helper_tags %}

{% block title %}
    {{ djname }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div>
        {{ event_track_form }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Would you mind to show both the `base.html` and the `other_template.html`?

Comment: Hi nik_m, I just updated my Q with actual code

Comment: Hmm... It seems like you're not rendering the `form` inside the `other_template.html`. You're doing it correclty when you render the `base.html` but not when you render the `other_template.html`. You should render each time the `form` object when a new `view` is displayed.

Comment: I was using the variable `event_track_form` passed through the context. I just changed the name to `form` and now it works... I guess it's somehow related to DAL internals...

Comment: That's great! Good work david. Post it as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: I've an open issue on their public repo https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/907 - as soon as I'm sure about it, I'll post a proper anser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A discussed in comments the solution is to pass the correct `form` object to the template. If it's been defined as `form_whatever` in the view, `form_whatever.media` must be used in the template.